# Computed field in mongoengine from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, mongodb, mongoengine

To avoid computing and setting fields explicitly on a mongoengine `Document`, I'd like to have it as a computed field. Is this currently possible?

Here's a MWE of what I'm expecting:

```
class Task(Document):
    meta = {"collection": "tasks"}

    @property
    def get_values_count(self):
        return len(self.values)

    dateAdded = DateTimeField()
    dateStarted = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())
    values = ListField(IntField())
    values_count = IntField(default=get_values_count) # Either this, normal class functions not supported by Documents
    # values_count = IntField(default = lambda : len(self.values)) //Or this (this won't compile)
```

Any way of achieving something like this?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, you don't want to store `values_count` in your database. So you can just use a `@property`

```
class Task(Document):
    meta = {"collection": "tasks"}

    @property
    def values_count(self):
        return len(self.values)

    dateAdded = DateTimeField()
    dateStarted = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())
    values = ListField(IntField())
```

Comment: I noticed after donig this, the field is present during debug but not included in the JSON response